# Using CMake to generate static library but some symbols are not archive in

Tags: c++, cmake

I use the below CMakeLists to generate a static library libwebrtc_fec.a

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project (webrtc_fec)

set(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR /root/git2/webrtc_extract/fec)
set(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR /root/git2/webrtc_extract)


set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

add_definitions(-DWEBRTC_POSIX)
#add_definitions(-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1)


set(link_library_path ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
                      /usr/lib
                      /usr/local/lib)
link_directories(${link_library_path})



set(header_path  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
                 ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
                 ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/abseil-cpp
                 /usr/include
                 /usr/local/include
                 )
include_directories(${header_path})

set(source_file fec_decode.cc
                fec_encode.cc
                ./include/fec_decode.h
                ./include/fec_encode.h) 


add_library(webrtc_fec STATIC ${source_file})

target_link_libraries(webrtc_fec "-Wl,--whole-archive" libwebrtc_rtp_rtcp.a)
```

But lots of symbols in libwebrtc_fec.a are undefined, such as symbol **webrtc::RtpPacketToSend::RtpPacketToSend**

```
> nm -C libwebrtc_fec.a | grep webrtc::RtpPacketToSend::RtpPacketToSend
U webrtc::RtpPacketToSend::RtpPacketToSend(webrtc::RtpHeaderExtensionMap const*)
```

It can be found in libwebrtc_rtp_rtcp.a and should be linked and package into libwebrtc_fec.a, why  it doesn't?

```
>nm -C libwebrtc_rtp_rtcp.a| grep webrtc::RtpPacketToSend::RtpPacketToSend
                 U webrtc::RtpPacketToSend::RtpPacketToSend(webrtc::RtpHeaderExtensionMap const*)
                 U webrtc::RtpPacketToSend::RtpPacketToSend(webrtc::RtpPacketToSend const&)
                 U webrtc::RtpPacketToSend::RtpPacketToSend(webrtc::RtpHeaderExtensionMap const*)
                 U webrtc::RtpPacketToSend::RtpPacketToSend(webrtc::RtpHeaderExtensionMap const*, unsigned long)
                 U webrtc::RtpPacketToSend::RtpPacketToSend(webrtc::RtpPacketToSend const&)
                 U webrtc::RtpPacketToSend::RtpPacketToSend(webrtc::RtpHeaderExtensionMap const*, unsigned long)
                 U webrtc::RtpPacketToSend::RtpPacketToSend(webrtc::RtpPacketToSend const&)
                 U webrtc::RtpPacketToSend::RtpPacketToSend(webrtc::RtpPacketToSend const&)
                 U webrtc::RtpPacketToSend::RtpPacketToSend(webrtc::RtpPacketToSend const&)
00000000000001c0 T webrtc::RtpPacketToSend::RtpPacketToSend(webrtc::RtpPacketToSend&&)
0000000000000000 T webrtc::RtpPacketToSend::RtpPacketToSend(webrtc::RtpHeaderExtensionMap const*)
0000000000000090 T webrtc::RtpPacketToSend::RtpPacketToSend(webrtc::RtpHeaderExtensionMap const*, unsigned long)
0000000000000120 T webrtc::RtpPacketToSend::RtpPacketToSend(webrtc::RtpPacketToSend const&)
00000000000001c0 T webrtc::RtpPacketToSend::RtpPacketToSend(webrtc::RtpPacketToSend&&)
0000000000000000 T webrtc::RtpPacketToSend::RtpPacketToSend(webrtc::RtpHeaderExtensionMap const*)
0000000000000090 T webrtc::RtpPacketToSend::RtpPacketToSend(webrtc::RtpHeaderExtensionMap const*, unsigned long)
0000000000000120 T webrtc::RtpPacketToSend::RtpPacketToSend(webrtc::RtpPacketToSend const&)
```

Comment: Static libraries are nothing more than archives of object files, they are not linked. And therefore your `target_link_libraries` is irrelevant. If you want a program to be linked with a static library, you need to explicitly link with its dependencies as well.

Comment: @Some programmer dude thanks, I have learnt a lot